# Defining a field dependent on enum value

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Suppose I have a message:

```
message A {
string id = 1;
string name = 2;
Enum company = 3;
string size = 4;
}
```

`size` should exist only when `company` has a particular enum value. Is there a way to define the proto so a field exists only when the other field has a particular value?

Answer (score 0):

Protocol buffers are used to define the schema of a message and not the contents of the message. If you don't want a field to "exist", simply don't set it. If you don't set the `size` field, it won't be included in the encoded message and any protocol buffer deserializer will give it a default value of empty string.

Your application logic should be able to check if the `company` enum is of a certain value before using the size field.

If you need the size field to take on a `null` value as the default, you can use a wrapped `StringValue` type instead.

```
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message A {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  Enum company = 3;
  google.protobuf.StringValue size = 4;
}
```

With this approach, you'll have to first check if `message.size` is not `null`, then get the actual string value out via `message.size.value`.

For more info on wrapped types, see https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto